# Visual Studio 2015 save location

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[image]

Why can  I not change the storage location?

Comment: what version of VS2015 are you using?

Comment: It looks like the window has been collapsed to hide the save location, try simply dragging down the bottom edge to reveal the directory boxes. You may have a low screen resolution or some kind of accessibility setting that eats up that space.

Comment: No, No ,But in others there .

Comment: Registration regulations in other places have not only this one.